# Entity Framework Code First Relationships: One to Many to Multiple Entities

Tags: c#, entity-framework

This is my first project using EF. I am creating a model with (this is an example) Movies and TV Series as entities. Both have notes tied to them. Note is an entity as well. I would like to have a one-to-many relationship between Movies -> Notes and TVSeries -> Notes. How can this be accomplished?

There needs to be something in Notes to define whether the note belongs to a movie or a series.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't create a child that has two different parents and have a proper primary/foreign key relationship between them.

One option, assuming that Movies and TVSeries have common properties, would be to use inheritance in the Movies/TV relationship and have the Notes hang off the superclass. Something like:

```
public abstract class EntertainmentBase
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    // other common properties
}

public class Movie
{
    // properties specific to a movie
}

public class TVSeries
{
    // properties specific to a TV Series
}

public class Note
{
    public int NoteId { get; set; }
    public int BaseEntertainmentId { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Craig! That's a bummer in my case. The entities I am working with dont really have any common properties, and notes need to be tied to each entity individually. I guess I will have to create two note entites: MovieNotes and TVSeriesNotes.

Comment: You can always create a Notes entity with what I've referred to in the past as a polymorphic foreign key. That means you store the key of the parent but you don't have any declarative referential integrity so your code has to know which parent to connect to. You also need to use something like GUIDs as your primary keys for the parent entities so you don't get collisions.

Comment: That makes sense. This application is being ported to .NET from ColdFusion and within the tables Notes had noteid, parentId, parentType properties. I was able to retrieve necessary notes using parentId and parentType combination. Your example seems to follow a similar pattern using the BaseEntertainment Class.

Comment: @Helius06 - Seriously?  There are *no* common properties?  Yet you somehow claim notes are common?  That's a common property.  How would Title not be common?  How would things like Cast, crew, director, not be common?

Comment: @ErikFunkenbusch - The entities I mentioned in my question were an example. The actual entities I am working with are different and don't have any common properties. Notes is the only common property between these entities.

Comment: @Helius06 - this is the problem with using examples that are not anything like your actual problem domain.  We end up solving problems based on the examples you provide, and that turns out to be wrong.  Try providing REAL examples (or at least fake ones that are similar to your problem domain)

Comment: @ErikFunkenbusch - Thanks Erik! I think Craig's idea solves my problem.